# Strange drop-outs in Cisco 7200 LNS lab

Tags: cisco, troubleshooting, cisco-ios-15, pppoe, l2tp

I'm testing several functions on emulated Cisco 7200 routers, in GNS3, prior to actual purchase.

One of the functions I've been testing out is LNS functionality. I've been primarily following [this blog post](http://ccieblog.co.uk/dsl/configuring-dsl) in terms of my topology and configuration, though IP addresses and names have changed as I've adapted my existing topology.

I'm trying to figure out why the dropouts are occurring, or at least what I more I could be looking at to diagnose the issue. Connectivity between CPE and my LNS is otherwise fine, aside from the regular disconnects.

**Before I go further:** I should mention that I've seen random drop outs with GNS3 when the host CPU is maxed out. In this case, the CPU is high, but not entirely maxed out, and seems to be running OK. I'm still suspicious it's a GNS3 specific issue, but I'm not sure.

In my topology:

All routers (CPE, LAC, LNS) are:

> Cisco IOS Software, 7200 Software (C7200-ADVIPSERVICESK9-M), Version 15.0(1)M, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
>
> Cisco 7206VXR (NPE400) processor (revision A) with 245760K/16384K bytes of memory.

- **EDGE01** is my LNS.
- **CPE-A** is the customer router.
- I do have my lab's upstream router acting as an LAC, but I'm not focusing on that, as I want to simulate solving the issue as I would if our LNS were in production - so I wouldn't typically have LAC logs readily available.

Everything seems to be working fine, although I have noticed that the CPE device seems to disconnect and reconnect, every few minutes. Though the timeouts are always similar, they aren't exactly the same:

```
EDGE01#sh logging | inc Foreign Host Close
*Mar  6 13:34:34.000: VPDN Vi2.1 disconnect (AAA) IETF: 8/port-error 
 Ascend: 41/TCP Foreign Host Close
*Mar  6 13:36:40.340: VPDN Vi2.1 disconnect (AAA) IETF: 8/port-error 
 Ascend: 41/TCP Foreign Host Close
*Mar  6 13:39:38.107: VPDN Vi2.1 disconnect (AAA) IETF: 8/port-error 
 Ascend: 41/TCP Foreign Host Close
*Mar  6 13:41:33.003: VPDN Vi2.1 disconnect (AAA) IETF: 8/port-error 
 Ascend: 41/TCP Foreign Host Close
EDGE01#
```

Here's some log samples of what's happening. I may not be reading them correctly, but it seems like both the CPE and the LNS are saying, "The other guy disconnected the session, not me."

**CPE Disconnecting**

```
*Mar  6 13:30:35.378: Vi1 LCP: I TERMREQ [Open] id 1 len 4
*Mar  6 13:30:35.394: Vi1 IPCP: Event[DOWN] State[Open to Starting]
*Mar  6 13:30:35.394: Vi1 IPCP: Event[CLOSE] State[Starting to Initial]
*Mar  6 13:30:35.398: Vi1 LCP: O TERMACK [Open] id 1 len 4
*Mar  6 13:30:35.398: Vi1 LCP: Event[Receive TermReq] State[Open to 
 Stopping]
*Mar  6 13:30:35.398: Vi1 PPP DISC: Received LCP TERMREQ from peer
*Mar  6 13:30:35.402: Vi1 PPP: Phase is TERMINATING
*Mar  6 13:30:35.426: Di1 IPCP: Remove route to 172.16.2.1
*Mar  6 13:30:35.650: PPPoE 1544: I PADT  R:ca03.0fa0.0008 
 L:ca0a.13a4.0008 Fa0/0
*Mar  6 13:30:35.650:  PPPoE : Shutting down client session
*Mar  6 13:30:35.650: [0]PPPoE 1544: O PADT  R:ca03.0fa0.0008 
 L:ca0a.13a4.0008 Fa0/0
*Mar  6 13:30:35.650: PPPoE: Failed to add PPPoE switching subblock
*Mar  6 13:30:35.650: %DIALER-6-UNBIND: Interface Vi1 unbound from 
 profile Di1
*Mar  6 13:30:35.650: Vi1 PPP: Block vaccess from being freed [0x10]
*Mar  6 13:30:35.650: Vi1
CPE-A#
LCP: Event[DOWN] State[Stopping to Starting]
*Mar  6 13:30:35.650: Vi1 PPP: Unlocked by [0x10] Still Locked by [0x0]
*Mar  6 13:30:35.650: Vi1 PPP: Free previously blocked vaccess
*Mar  6 13:30:35.650: Vi1 PPP: Phase is DOWN
*Mar  6 13:30:35.654: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Virtual-Access1, changed 
 state to down
*Mar  6 13:30:35.658: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface 
 Virtual-Access1, changed state to down
*Mar  6 13:30:35.682: PPPoE: Unexpected Event!. PPPoE switching 
 Subblockdestroy called
```

**LNS Disconnecting**

```
EDGE01#
L2X_ADJ: Vi2.1:adj notify change, event 4
L2X_ADJ: Vi2.1:midchain unstacking IP 0.0.0.0
L2X_ADJ: Vi2.1:adj notify change, event 8
*Mar  6 14:39:33.227: VPDN Vi2.1 disconnect (AAA) IETF: 8/port-error 
 Ascend: 41/TCP Foreign Host Close
*Mar  6 14:39:33.235: VPDN Vi2.1 vpdn shutdown session, result=2, error=6, 
 vendor_err=0, syslog_error_code=23, syslog_key_type=1
*Mar  6 14:39:33.243: VPDN Vi2.1 VPDN/AAA: accounting stop sent
*Mar  6 14:39:33.255: VPDN Vi2.1 Unbinding session from idb
*Mar  6 14:39:33.263: Vi2.1 VPDN: Resetting interface
L2X_ADJ: Vi2.1:midchain unstacking IP 0.0.0.0
L2X_ADJ: Vi2.1:removed ctx
```

**LNS Re-Connecting**

```
*Mar  6 13:30:58.604: VPDN Received L2TUN socket message <xCRQ - Session 
 Incoming>
*Mar  6 13:30:58.608: VPDN Tnl/Sn 41793 56421 L2TUN socket session accept 
 requested
*Mar  6 13:30:58.612: VPDN Tnl/Sn 41793 56421 Setting up dataplane for 
 L2-L2, no idb
*Mar  6 13:30:58.880: VPDN Received L2TUN socket message <xCCN - Session 
 Connected>
*Mar  6 13:30:58.892: VPDN uid:330 VPDN session up
L2X_ADJ: Vi2.1:midchain adj reqd for ip 0.0.0.0, cid 0
L2X_ADJ: Vi2.1:midchain adj reqd for ip 0.0.0.0, cid 0
*Mar  6 13:30:59.112: VPDN uid:330 Virtual interface created for 
 cpe-a@isp.com
bandwidth 100000 Kbps
```

**CPE Re-Connecting**

```
*Mar  6 13:30:55.674:  Sending PADI: Interface = FastEthernet0/0
*Mar  6 13:30:55.686: PPPoE 0: I PADO  R:ca03.0fa0.0008 L:ca0a.13a4.0008 
 Fa0/0
CPE-A#
*Mar  6 13:30:57.722:  PPPOE: we've got our pado and the pado timer went off
*Mar  6 13:30:57.722: OUT PADR from PPPoE Session
*Mar  6 13:30:57.822: PPPoE 1545: I PADS  R:ca03.0fa0.0008 L:ca0a.13a4.0008
 Fa0/0
*Mar  6 13:30:57.822: IN PADS from PPPoE Session
*Mar  6 13:30:57.838: %DIALER-6-BIND: Interface Vi1 bound to profile Di1
*Mar  6 13:30:57.842: PPPoE: Virtual Access interface obtained.
*Mar  6 13:30:57.842: PPPoE : encap string prepared
*Mar  6 13:30:57.842: [0]PPPoE 1545: data path set to PPPoE Client
*Mar  6 13:30:57.854: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Virtual-Access1, changed 
 state to up
*Mar  6 13:30:57.854: Vi1 PPP: Sending cstate UP notification
*Mar  6 13:30:57.858: Vi1 PPP: Processing CstateUp message
*Mar  6 13:30:57.906: PPP: Alloc Context [66CDB580]
*Mar  6 13:30:57.906: ppp622 PPP: Phase is ESTABLISHING
*Mar  6 13:30:57.910: Vi1 PPP: Using dialer call direction
*Mar  6 13:30:57.910: Vi1 PPP: Treating connection as a callout
*Mar  6 13:30:57.910: Vi1 PPP:
CPE-A#
Session handle[F400069A] Session id[622]
*Mar  6 13:30:57.914: Vi1 LCP: Event[OPEN] State[Initial to Starting]
*Mar  6 13:30:57.914: Vi1 PPP: No remote authentication for call-out
*Mar  6 13:30:57.918: Vi1 LCP: O CONFREQ [Starting] id 1 len 10
*Mar  6 13:30:57.918: Vi1 LCP:    MagicNumber 0x191D3E68 (0x0506191D3E68)
*Mar  6 13:30:57.922: Vi1 LCP: Event[UP] State[Starting to REQsent]
*Mar  6 13:30:58.042: Vi1 LCP: I CONFREQ [REQsent] id 1 len 18
*Mar  6 13:30:58.046: Vi1 LCP:    MRU 1492 (0x010405D4)
*Mar  6 13:30:58.046: Vi1 LCP:    AuthProto PAP (0x0304C023)
*Mar  6 13:30:58.046: Vi1 LCP:    MagicNumber 0x2686484A (0x05062686484A)
*Mar  6 13:30:58.050: Vi1 LCP: O CONFNAK [REQsent] id 1 len 8
*Mar  6 13:30:58.050: Vi1 LCP:    MRU 1500 (0x010405DC)
*Mar  6 13:30:58.050: Vi1 LCP: Event[Receive ConfReq-] State[REQsent to 
 REQsent]
*Mar  6 13:30:58.106: Vi1 LCP: I CONFACK [REQsent] id 1 len 10
*Mar  6 13:30:58.106: Vi1 LCP:    MagicNumber 0x191D3E68 (0x0506191D3E68)
*Mar  6
CPE-A#13:30:58.106: Vi1 LCP: Event[Receive ConfAck] State[REQsent to 
 ACKrcvd]
*Mar  6 13:30:58.110: Vi1 LCP: I CONFREQ [ACKrcvd] id 2 len 18
*Mar  6 13:30:58.110: Vi1 LCP:    MRU 1500 (0x010405DC)
*Mar  6 13:30:58.110: Vi1 LCP:    AuthProto PAP (0x0304C023)
*Mar  6 13:30:58.110: Vi1 LCP:    MagicNumber 0x2686484A (0x05062686484A)
*Mar  6 13:30:58.114: Vi1 LCP: O CONFACK [ACKrcvd] id 2 len 18
*Mar  6 13:30:58.114: Vi1 LCP:    MRU 1500 (0x010405DC)
*Mar  6 13:30:58.114: Vi1 LCP:    AuthProto PAP (0x0304C023)
*Mar  6 13:30:58.114: Vi1 LCP:    MagicNumber 0x2686484A (0x05062686484A)
*Mar  6 13:30:58.118: Vi1 LCP: Event[Receive ConfReq+] State[ACKrcvd to 
 Open]
*Mar  6 13:30:58.122: Vi1 PPP: No authorization without authentication
*Mar  6 13:30:58.126: Vi1 PPP: Phase is AUTHENTICATING, by the peer
*Mar  6 13:30:58.126: Vi1 PAP: Using hostname from interface PAP
*Mar  6 13:30:58.126: Vi1 PAP: Using password from interface PAP
*Mar  6 13:30:58.126: Vi1 PAP: O AUTH-REQ id 1 len 26 from
CPE-A# "cpe-a@isp.com"
*Mar  6 13:30:58.130: Vi1 LCP: State is Open
*Mar  6 13:30:59.390: Vi1 PAP: I AUTH-ACK id 1 len 5
*Mar  6 13:30:59.394: Vi1 PPP: Phase is FORWARDING, Attempting Forward
*Mar  6 13:30:59.394: Vi1 PPP: Queue IPCP code[1] id[1]
*Mar  6 13:30:59.422: Vi1 PPP: Phase is ESTABLISHING, Finish LCP
*Mar  6 13:30:59.426: Vi1 PPP: Phase is UP
*Mar  6 13:30:59.426: Vi1 IPCP: Protocol configured, start CP. 
 state[Initial]
*Mar  6 13:30:59.426: Vi1 IPCP: Event[OPEN] State[Initial to Starting]
*Mar  6 13:30:59.430: Vi1 IPCP: O CONFREQ [Starting] id 1 len 10
*Mar  6 13:30:59.430: Vi1 IPCP:    Address 0.0.0.0 (0x030600000000)
*Mar  6 13:30:59.434: Vi1 IPCP: Event[UP] State[Starting to REQsent]
*Mar  6 13:30:59.434: Vi1 PPP: Process pending ncp packets
*Mar  6 13:30:59.434: Vi1 IPCP: Redirect packet to Vi1
*Mar  6 13:30:59.434: Vi1 IPCP: I CONFREQ [REQsent] id 1 len 10
*Mar  6 13:30:59.438: Vi1 IPCP:    Address 172.16.2.1 (0x0306AC100201)
*Mar  6 13:30:59.442: Vi1 IPCP:
CPE-A# O CONFACK [REQsent] id 1 len 10
*Mar  6 13:30:59.442: Vi1 IPCP:    Address 172.16.2.1 (0x0306AC100201)
*Mar  6 13:30:59.442: Vi1 IPCP: Event[Receive ConfReq+] State[REQsent to 
 ACKsent]
*Mar  6 13:30:59.446: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface 
 Virtual-Access1, changed state to up
*Mar  6 13:30:59.602: Vi1 IPCP: I CONFNAK [ACKsent] id 1 len 10
*Mar  6 13:30:59.602: Vi1 IPCP:    Address 172.16.2.19 (0x0306AC100213)
*Mar  6 13:30:59.606: Vi1 IPCP: O CONFREQ [ACKsent] id 2 len 10
*Mar  6 13:30:59.606: Vi1 IPCP:    Address 172.16.2.19 (0x0306AC100213)
*Mar  6 13:30:59.606: Vi1 IPCP: Event[Receive ConfNak/Rej] State[ACKsent to
 ACKsent]
*Mar  6 13:30:59.826: Vi1 IPCP: I CONFACK [ACKsent] id 2 len 10
*Mar  6 13:30:59.826: Vi1 IPCP:    Address 172.16.2.19 (0x0306AC100213)
*Mar  6 13:30:59.826: Vi1 IPCP: Event[Receive ConfAck] State[ACKsent to 
 Open]
*Mar  6 13:30:59.842: Vi1 IPCP: State is Open
*Mar  6 13:30:59.846: Di1 IPCP: Install negotiated IP interface address 
 172.16.2.19
*Mar  6 13:30:59.854: Di1 IPCP: Install route to 172.16.2.1
CPE-A#
```

Relevant configs...

**The LAC:**

```
no aaa new-model
!
ip source-route
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
no ip domain lookup
no ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
vpdn enable
vpdn search-order domain
!
vpdn-group PPP-Customers
 request-dialin
  protocol l2tp
  domain isp.com
 initiate-to ip 10.27.200.2
 local name LAC
 l2tp tunnel password 0 tunnel123
!
!
redundancy
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
!
bba-group pppoe isp
 virtual-template 1
!
!
interface Loopback0
 description Management Loopback
 ip address 10.27.100.1 255.255.255.255
 !
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 description PtP to CPE
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 pppoe enable group isp
 !
!
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 description PtP LAC-EDGE01
 ip address 10.27.200.1 255.255.255.252
 duplex full
 speed 100
 !
!
interface Virtual-Template1
 ip unnumbered Loopback0
 ppp authentication pap chap
 !
!
router bgp 100
 no synchronization
 bgp router-id 10.27.100.1
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 10.27.200.2 remote-as 165535
 neighbor 10.27.200.2 password BGP123
 no auto-summary
!
```

**The LNS:**

> EDGE01#sh debug
>
> VPN:
>
> VPDN events debugging is on

```
aaa new-model
!
!
aaa authentication ppp default local
aaa authentication ppp PPPNetBlock local
!
!
!
!
!
aaa session-id common
!
!
!
ip source-route
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
no ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
vpdn enable
!
vpdn-group PPP-Customers
 accept-dialin
  protocol l2tp
  virtual-template 1
 terminate-from hostname LAC
 local name LNS
 no l2tp tunnel authentication
 l2tp tunnel password 0 tunnel123
 l2tp tunnel timeout no-session 15
!
!
!
!
!
username cpe-a@isp.com password 0 cpe123
!
redundancy
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
!
interface Loopback0
 description Management Loopback
 ip address 172.16.3.1 255.255.255.255
 !
 !
interface Loopback1
 description PPP Customers GW Loopback
 ip address 172.16.2.1 255.255.255.255
 !
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 description PtP EDGE01-LAC
 ip address 10.27.200.2 255.255.255.252
 duplex full
 speed 100
 !
!
interface Virtual-Template1
 description PPP Customers Template
 ip unnumbered Loopback1
 peer default ip address pool PPPNetBlock
 ppp authentication pap chap
 !
!
! For this lab, I am redistributing CPE IPs into OSPF instead of BGP.
router ospf 1
 router-id 172.16.3.1
 log-adjacency-changes
 auto-cost reference-bandwidth 512000
 redistribute connected subnets
 network 172.16.3.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 default-information originate
!
! BGP with upstream router, which is also the LAC.
! BGP session is kind of irrelevant, though.
router bgp 165535
 no synchronization
 bgp router-id 10.27.200.2
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 10.27.200.1 remote-as 100
 neighbor 10.27.200.1 password BGP123
 no auto-summary
!
ip local pool PPPNetBlock 172.16.2.2 172.16.2.254
ip forward-protocol nd
```

**The CPE:**

> CPE-A#sh debug
>
> PPP:
>
> PPP authentication debugging is on
>
> PPP protocol errors debugging is on
>
> PPP protocol negotiation debugging is on
>
> PPPoE:
>
> PPPoE protocol events debugging is on
>
> PPPoE protocol errors debugging is on

```
no aaa new-model
!
ip source-route
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
no ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
redundancy
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 description DSL
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 pppoe enable
 pppoe-client dial-pool-number 1
 !
!
interface Dialer1
 description DSL Dialer
 ip address negotiated
 ip mtu 1492
 encapsulation ppp
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1452
 dialer pool 1
 ppp authentication chap callin
 ppp chap hostname cpe-a@isp.com
 ppp chap password 0 cpe123
 ppp pap sent-username cpe-a@isp.com password 0 cpe123
 no cdp enable
!
!
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer1
!
```

Comment: Try putting dialer persistent and dialer idle timeout 0 on the CPE's dialer interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testing that kind of features using GNS3 is simply waste of time. You're emulating at run-time complex software, and on top of that, you're adding complex features.

There's no sense in 'trying' 7200 as 7200 are long EoS:
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/7200-series-routers/end_of_life_c51-681414.html

Download CSR 1000v and test in on some decent hypervisor, you may get better luck, but on IOS-XE you'll have different configuration templates.

Comment: Yes, I understand. It was more a case of wanting to ensure that the 7200 series is capable of working as an LNS, as a proof of concept. And I've never configured an LNS or worked with a 7200 before. I've essentially achieved that, but I wasn't sure if the drop outs were my config, or just GNS3. But I'm inclined to agree that it's GNS3.

Comment: And yes, I realise the 7200 series is EOL. Unfortunately, we have nowhere near the budget required for an ASR1K or Juniper's MX Series, right now - so compromises had to be made.

Comment: ASR1001 is exactly on the price the 7200/NPE-G2 was, and it has hardware forwarding path, so you'll get more for the same price you anyway ment to spend. For 7200 - yes, as internet shows with thousands of such installations, 7200 can act as LNS.

Comment: You're starting to come across as a bit condescending, and I'm not sure what I've done to warrant that. Yes, I know the internet has many guides, which I've looked at, but I wanted to have a proof of concept myself to ensure that I understood the examples and could get it working myself. Call me pedantic.

Comment: I agree the ASR1001 is better value for money, but I also know it's overkill for our needs right now, it's like purchasing an entire cage when you only need one rack. You might technically get better $/RU but if a cage is beyond your budget, then it's really irrelevant. Maybe the 7200 used to be at the same price point, but it isn't anymore, so that's why we can afford a 7200 (even new) but not an ASR1K. I agree with your advice, but I've spent months on and off looking at various hardware and at this point know what we can and can't afford.

Comment: Anyway. Thanks for all your advice, I will not be testing LNS functionality any further until I have the physical hardware.